# Relationships in Phalcon

Tags: php, relationship, phalcon

I'm working on a multilanguage project and I need help on getting proper language from database.

In my session I have stored lang code and id from database tabe:

DB TABLE languages

```
ID    lang_code   lang
1     en-us       English (US)
2     es-ES       Spanish (ES)
3     de-DE       Deutsch (DE)
```

Then I have two tables for menu

DB TABLE menu

```
ID    parent    link
1     null      intro/
2     null      about/
3     null      terms/
```

and DB TABLE menu_translation

```
ID    menu_id    lang_id    title
1     1          1          Intro
2     2          1          About
3     3          1          Terms & Conditions
4     1          2          Intro
```

In my models I did this

MODEL Languages

```
<?php
class Languages extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public $id;
    public $lang_code;
    public $lang;
}
```

MODEL Menu

```
<?php
class Menu extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public $id;
    public $parent;
    public $link;
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'Menu', 'parent');
    }
}
```

this parent is because I have nested menus so I need to put which menu belong to which menu.

MODEL MenuTranslation

```
<?php
class MenuTranslation extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public $id;
    public $menu_id;
    public $lang_id;
    public $title;
}
```

My question is how to set relation so I can get only MenuTranslation for language that is set in session so later I can display something like:

```
{% for item in menu %}
    {{ menu.menuTranslation.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is it even possible and if it is how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong relation in the Menu model.

MODEL Menu

```
<?php
class Menu extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
public $id;
public $parent;
public $link;
public function initialize() {
    $this->hasMany('id', 'MenuTranslation', 'menu_id');
}
}
```

MODEL MenuTranslation

```
<?php
class MenuTranslation extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
public $id;
public $menu_id;
public $lang_id;
public $title;

   public function initialize()
   {
      $this->hasMany('menu_id', 'Menu', 'id');
      $this->hasMany('lang_id', 'Languages', 'id');
   }
}
```

Template

```
{% for item in menu %}
{{ menu.getMenuTranslation().getLanguages().title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, I would recomend you to create a custom query JOIN'ing all 3 tables in 1 query.